# deviceShaken() and deviceMoved() not working on p5.js sketch

Tags: javascript, p5.js

```
function deviceMoved(){
  moved = true;
  bulb.stop();
  playing = false;
}
```

On my sketch.js (p5.js) this event is not fired on mobile phone, neither is deviceShaken(). 
Google Chrome version is around 80 or something, my phone is a Huawei P20 Lite. 
I'm using http, but https as well did not produce any result. 
Anyone know why or how to solve this issue?

Comment: Maybe you need to set correct permissions to access accelerometer and gyroscope.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but how would I do that?
I mean, code-wise could you link me an example?

Comment: I meant to say your device permissions needed to be tweaked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved!
It was a rather tricky one. 
In both Android and iOS you'll need to enable https. 
In iOS 13+ you'll also need to ask for permission (and it needs to be done within a user interaction).

Something like this:

```
if (typeof DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission === 'function' &&
typeof DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission === 'function'
 ) {
 // iOS 13+
  askButton = createButton('Permission');
  askButton.size(windowWidth*6/8, windowHeight/8);
  askButton.position(windowWidth/2 - drumButton.width/2, windowHeight/2);
  askButton.mousePressed(() => {
    DeviceMotionEvent.requestPermission()
    .then(response => {
      if (response === 'granted') {
        window.addEventListener('devicemotion', deviceMotionHandler, true);
      }
    });

    DeviceOrientationEvent.requestPermission()
    .then(response => {
    if (response === 'granted') {
      window.addEventListener('deviceorientation', deviceTurnedHandler, true)
    }
  })
  .catch(console.error)
```